# Update component state from Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I get from redux store some config

```
dispatch(aOrder.getThrottlingConfig(storeId))
```

after that, I want to set value  from redux to the component store

```
const throttlingConfig: IOrderConfig = useSelector<RootState, IOrderConfig>(({ root }) => root.order.throttling)
setCapacity(throttlingConfig.throttling.context.capacity)
```

But when component mount throttling is undefined, if try make the condition

```
if (throttlingConfig.throttling) {
     setCapacity(throttlingConfig.throttling.context.capacity)
    }
```

it never executes, what am I doing wrong?
I want just setState from Redux store when their field what I need is  updated

Comment: Did you extract setCapacity from props?

Comment: No, it's just hook
const [capacity, setCapacity] = useState(null)

Answer (score 1):

In this block you're assigning `root.order.throttling` to `throttlingConfig` then when you're accessing it you're trying to access `throttlingConfig.throttling.context.capacity`.

```
const throttlingConfig: IOrderConfig = useSelector<RootState, IOrderConfig>(({ root }) => root.order.throttling) setCapacity(throttlingConfig.throttling.context.capacity)
```

Which would actually be `root.order.throttling.throttling.context.capacity`.

So, assuming your data is structured as I expect, this *should* work:

```
if (throttlingConfig) {
 setCapacity(throttlingConfig.context.capacity)
}
```